# Why does my ansible template file have no substitutions?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible template file which I'm applying correctly with the 'template' directive, but it's showing up on the remote machine with no substitutions:

```
- name: "buildAgent.properties for {{ agent_name }}"
  template:
    src: buildAgent.properties.j2
    dest: "{{ config_path }}/buildAgent.properties"
```

The template file looks something like this:

```
serverUrl={{ teamcity_url }}
name={{ agent_name }}

{% if teamcity_agent_variables %}
{% for variable in teamcity_agent_variables %}
{{ variable }}={{ teamcity_agent_variables[variable] }}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
# no teamcity_agent_variables from ansible
{% endif %}
```

and when it arrived on the remote machine, without errors from ansible, it looked exactly the same - even though when I displayed the variables in the step before the template step, they existed

---

Update: version stuff.

```
% ansible --version                                     
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /Users/timb/git/mre-ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/timb/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.3.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/timb/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Aug 30 2022, 05:12:36) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True

% grep error_on  /Users/timb/git/mre-ansible/ansible.cfg

#error_on_missing_handler = True
error_on_undefined_vars = True
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the teamcity_agent_variables had been over-ridden in one file by a list instead of a hash, so the attempts to deference it failed.

I have no idea why Ansible didn't print a useful error when jinja failed - nor indeed when the type of the variable changed - instead of simply copying the template.

Comment: With modern Ansible's default settings, this will result in an error. Seeing an untemplated file instead implies that you are either using Ansible 1.2 or earlier, or have deliberately enabled the ancient behaviour for undefined variables (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-undefined-var-behavior). Either of these is very unwise.

Comment: @flowerysong Thanks for the comment. I did think it was rather strange behaviour for a relatively mature utility. I'm on Ansible core 2.13.3 and jinja 3.1.2, and ansible.cfg has error_on_undefined_vars = True (which is the default anyway).